# Ir buscar valor á tabela e colocar em formulário

Tags: jquery, html, tabela-html

Essa é a tabela tem os campos o objetivo é clicar no botão de editar e ao clicar a instrução **jquery** que pus em cima vai preencher os campos automaticamente referentes a linha que foi clicada

É o seguinte eu quero pegar nos registos da tabela e colocá-los em um modal em input text e utilizei o código seguinte (Ele está a funcionar mas apenas para `<input type="text">` mas para `textarea` e `combobox` não funciona e é isso que eu quero)

```
<script>
    $('body').on("click", ".edit", function() {
        $('#alterar_ID').val($(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(0).text());
        $('#alterar_si').val($(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(0).text());
        $('#alterar_nome').val($(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(1).text());
        $('#alterar_data').val($(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(2).text());
        $('#alterar_duracao').val($(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(3).text());
        $('#alterar_tipo').val($(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(4).text());
        $('#alterar_relatorio').val($(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(5).text());

    });
</script>
```

Ou seja, ao clicar num botão da tabela ela vai buscar os valores correspondentes aos índices e vai colocá-los nos inputs do modal. A minha pergunta é a seguinte e se eu quiser colocar em uma *textarea* ou deixar selecionado uma *combobox*?

Comment: Para ambos a mesma forma funciona, tanto que se você fizer `$('#alterar_nome').val()` covê vai obter o valor deste campo. Você pode usar o `.va()` normalmente

Comment: poderia postar o código html ou o MCVE da sua duvida?

Comment: é colocar a combobox com o a string igual á da tabela ou seja no caso do campo nome de cliente ao editar deixar selecionado o nome do cliente respetivo ao nome de cliente da linha que foi premido o botao

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70531/discussion-between-dvd-and-shider).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que ao pegar o texto na tabela, não está combinando com o valor na combobox porque texto capturado da tabela vem com espaços, e não vai combinar com o valor do `select`.

Para resolver isso, use sempre `.trim()`, que irá limpar os espaços:

```
$('#alterar_tipo').val($(this).parents('tr').find('td').eq(4).text().trim());
```